# Converting EDT to EST in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have about 10,000 timestamps that I want to all be in EST. Some of the timestamps are already in EST, while others are in EDT. For each timestamp I have the date and time in format 11/15/15 13:51. I have tried the following code:

```
times<- as.POSIXct(x=RacDat$Begin.Time, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="America/New_York")

times<- attr(times, "tzone") <- "UTC" 
times<- attr(times, "tzone") <- "America/New_York"
```

I hoped that by converting to UTC and then back to America/NewYork time zone I would convert all times to EST, but it seems that this still accounts for DST. Does anyone have experience with or solutions to this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: R is determining EST vs EDT for "America/New_York" depending on the date and time. If you prefer to have a fixed value compared to UTC, consider using UTC and subtracting 5.

Answer (score 1):

From user @Ian Campbell

"R is determining EST vs EDT for "America/New_York" depending on the date and time. If you prefer to have a fixed value compared to UTC, consider using UTC and subtracting 5."

This worked perfectly, thank you so much Ian!